# Addressing a data array returned from class get function in Matlab

Tags: oop, class, matlab

I am trying to find a nice solution for the following situation:

I have a class:

```
classdef SomeClass < handle

    properties (Access = private)
        x
    end

    methods
        function x = getX(this)
            x = this.x;
        end
    end
end
```

Let `x` - some data array.
Do I have a possibility to address some element of array like I'd make it in struct:

```
struct.x(5)
```

Or do I always have to do like this?:

```
myClassObj = SomeClass();
x = myClassObj.getX();
x(5)
```

or create some func getXAt?

Comment: Why is the property `private` but a getX() defined? Do you want to make `x` readable but not writable by other classes? And will all properties of this class be arrays of the same size?

Comment: Because I used to program in Java and was not sure that it's a good way to do it in this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Addressing like that is the normal behavior of a property in a Matlab object. You can just expose the property for reading instead of making it fully `private`.

```
classdef SomeClass < handle

    properties (SetAccess=private)
        x
    end

    methods
        function obj = SomeClass(x)
            obj.x = x;
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can address it like a field on a struct.

```
>> sc = SomeClass(1:7);
>> sc.x(5)
ans =
     5
>>
```

There's no need in Matlab to always make your own accessor functions like you would in Java. You can independently control the read and write access of a property using attributes on it. If you want more complex property access logic, you can define getters and setters using the special `function out = get.x(obj)` syntax, and their behavior will apply to property access done with the `obj.x` syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about it but was not sure

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, any class is an *array* of classes.

Therefore, you can write your class in this way:

```
classdef SomeClass < handle

    properties (Access = private)
        x
    end

    methods (Access=public)        
        function this = SomeClass(x)
            this.x = x;
        end
    end

    methods
        function x = getX(this)                
            x = [this.x];
        end
    end
end
```

And access like this:

> s(1) = SomeClass(1);
>   s(2) = SomeClass(5);
>   s(3) = SomeClass(6);
>
> s.getX()
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 1     5     6
> ```
>
> s(2).getX()
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 5
> ```

Comment: It's misleading to call this "vectorized". Splitting the data fields across object elements actually prevents you from doing vectorized operations on the fields without expensive array reconstruction first. May well be the right design, but "vectorized" is probably the wrong term. Previous versions of Matlab doco called this a "struct organized" class, as opposed to a "planar organized" class.

Comment: @Andrey, Thanks for the tip. I didn't know it. But for my situation I think it is not the perfect way, cause x can be pretty big in my case and than we need a huge among of objects.